# get_plugins() is not give plugin list after performed delete_plugins()

Tags: plugin-development

Upon performing delete_plugins() action, get_plugins() is give deleted plugin list.

For example:

```
delete_plugins(array('akismet/akismet.php'));
get_plugins();
```

Is I am doing something wrong? Any one give some insight about it.

Comment: Are you sure the plugin got deleted? Have you checked the `plugins` directory?

Comment: yes the plugin was deleted but also listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your main question, you are missing one line before calling `get_plugins()`. Without it, the list of plugins will come from cache. You can use the following sequence:

```
delete_plugins( array( 'akismet/akismet.php' ) );
wp_clean_plugins_cache( false );
get_plugins();
```

**`WARNING:`** it is not recommended using `delete_plugins()` in scripts, unless it is a part of complete procedure consisting of deactivation, uninstallation, and then deletion.

Comment: @Kuppuraj: it is still too early to delete plugins. Skipping phase of uninstallation, prevents plugins from cleaning up their settings and/or  tables from database.